# Getting different results due to date filtering method in SAS Proc SQL

Tags: sql, date, sas, proc-sql

I have a code chunk where I get different results based on how I filter for dates.

```
libname orac oracle authdomain= XX path =XX schema = XX;
proc sql;
create table ship_bill_date as (
select distinct(t.shp_pro),min(t.blng_dt) as blng_dt,count(t.shp_pro) as count 
from orac.table_A t
where blng_dt between '01-MAY-2023'd and '31-MAY-2023'd
);
quit;
```

The above code gives the expected 2+ million rows. However since I want the date filter to be dynamic I changed the code to the following.

```
libname orac oracle authdomain= XX path =XX schema = XX;
proc sql;
create table ship_bill_date as (
select distinct(t.shp_pro),min(t.blng_dt) as blng_dt,count(t.shp_pro) as count 
from orac.table_A t
where blng_dt between intnx('month', blng_dt, -2, 'b') and intnx('month', blng_dt, -2, 'e')
);
quit;
```

The above code chunk gives only 770 rows of output.
How can I rectify this?
The data type of blng_dt column is date.

Comment: Your second WHERE condition is completely different from the first.  And it makes no sense.  How can BLNG_DT by less than some date that is two months before it?  I suspect you are only getting the observations with missing BLNG_DT values.

Comment: I was looking for blng_dt to be between 01-May-23 and 31-May-23 just like the first code. I have also tried this code but the results are the same.

where blng_dt between (INTNX('MONTH',t.blng_dt,-2)) and (INTNX('MONTH',(INTNX('MONTH',t.blng_dt,-2)),0,"ENDING"))

Comment: I get what you are saying...I need to replace the blng_dt in the where statement with today()

Comment: Correct, if you want it dynamic off today's date, use the today() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the month that is 2 months before TODAY() then just do that.

```
where blng_dt between intnx('month',today(),-2) and intnx('month',today(),-2,'e')
```

If PROC SQL is too dumb to understand the range is a constant and optimize the query properly then use macro code instead.

```
where blng_dt between %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-2))
                  and %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-2,e))
```

If you want the values that %SYSFUNC() generates to be readable by humans add the optional format specification and generate date literals instead of just literal number of days.

```
10   %put
11   where blng_dt between "%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-2),date11)"d
12   and "%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-2,e),date11)"d
13   ;
where blng_dt between "01-MAY-2023"d and "31-MAY-2023"d
```